# Which collider should I use for a bucket?

Tags: unity, collider

I have a bucket, and I want a ball to be able to enter it. I'm facing a problem: Unity mesh collider seems not work with concave object... is that true? How can I solve this?

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.imgur.com/W5nv0Ki.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [mesh collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html), set the mesh, and disable the "Convex" checkbox.

Comment: I don't know it seems it didn't work :(

Comment: @stighy If this "does not work" for you, you should edit your question to explain how and provide additional details about how your collider(s) and scene are set up, such a screenshots of the properties of the objects in the inspector, et cetera. Since it's been shown to work for two people, there must be something different in your setup from theirs.